# how do you define an exact case constant with a switch statement in c++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and I don't fully understand how case works in switch statements. I have the following code:

```
bool accept3() {

    int tries = 1;

    while (tries<4) {
        std::cout<<"Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";
        char answer = 0;
        std::cin>>answer;

        switch(answer) {
        case 'y':
            return true;
        case 'n':
            return false;
        default:
            std::cout<<"Sorry, but I don't understand that.\n";
            tries ++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "I'll take that as a no.\n";
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    //accept();
    //accept2();
    accept3();
}
```

It works as expected when you input, 'y', 'n', or any other single character that does not meet the two defined cases.

**When you input any string of characters that begins with n, it still takes that as the  'n' case. Why does it do this? How can I make this more exact, so that it ONLY accepts 'n' and not 'no', 'no way' or any other string beginning with 'n'.**

Thank you!

Comment: `cin.getline` will grab an entire line of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you input any string of characters that begins with n, it still takes that as the 'n' case. Why does it do this?

Because you are asking `cin` to read a single `char`, so that is what it does.  `operator>>(char&)` ignores leading whitespace, if any, and then reads 1 `char`. Any subsequent characters, if any, are left in the input buffer for later reads.

> How can I make this more exact, so that it ONLY accepts 'n' and not 'no', 'no way' or any other string beginning with 'n'.

Use `cin.getline()` or `std::getline()` instead, and then compare the entire line, eg:

```
bool accept3() {

    int tries = 1;
    std::string answer;

    do {
        std::cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";
        std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, answer);

        if (answer == "y")
            return true;
        if (answer == "n")
            return false;

        std::cout << "Sorry, but I don't understand that.\n";
        ++tries;
    }
    while (tries < 4);

    std::cout << "I'll take that as a no.\n";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because if you input text with spaces into the terminal, like "d d d y", then you'll see the loop trigger 4 times in a row because "cin >> answer" breaks the line into separate inputs (this is called tokenization).

Here's code demonstrating how to properly parse an entire line of input as one menu command:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool accept3() {

    int tries = 1;

    while (tries < 4) {
        std::cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";
        std::string answerStr;
        std::getline(std::cin, answerStr);
        
        char answer = '\0';
        if (answerStr.size() == 1) {
            answer = answerStr[0];
        }

        switch (answer) {
        case 'y':
            return true;
        case 'n':
            return false;
        default:
            std::cout << "Sorry, but I don't understand that.\n";
            tries++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "I'll take that as a no.\n";
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    //accept();
    //accept2();
    accept3();
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh thank you! Tokenization is the piece I was missing.

Comment: Just note that `std::getline()` does not ignore leading whitespace, like `operator>>` does. So, if the user typed in `" n"` (or any amount of whitespace) into `answerStr`, your code won't catch the `n` properly. To fix that, you can use `std::cin >> std::ws` before calling `std::getline()`.